# Problem in Installing xdman in Ubuntu via terminal

Tags: java

I downloaded xdman in Ubuntu via the terminal using the command,

```
apt-get install xdman
```

However upon downloading when I try to run xdman using the "xdman" command in the terminal I got error message as,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/shabirmean/.xdmconf (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:140)
at org.sdg.xdman.core.common.XDMConfig.load(XDMConfig.java:118)
at org.sdg.xdman.gui.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:2724)
Config port: 9614
XDM Module running on: 9614
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/shabirmean/.xdmlist (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:140)
at org.sdg.xdman.gui.DownloadList.loadDownloadList(DownloadList.java:169)
at org.sdg.xdman.gui.DownloadList.<init>(DownloadList.java:44)
at org.sdg.xdman.gui.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:2746)
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:547)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
at org.sdg.xdman.gui.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:166)
at org.sdg.xdman.gui.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:2748)
```

Can anyone please help me get past this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the **OpenJDK's** java distribution. I installed Oracle JDK 8 and tried installation and it worked perfectly fine!!!!! So the error messages printed doesn't mean much at all (atleast for my case) as suggested in many of the other websites as a solution for this problem,

Answer (score 0):

Problem is **"Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException** which means the Java Runtime is Console only [Headless] (does not supports GUI application).
Please install correct JRE (i.e Full OpenJDK instead of OpenJDK headless) to solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit your answer to include the commands needed to install the missing packages.