# xdman don't work

Tags: 14.04

I am using 14.04 LTS
I have tried to start xdman from the terminal via:

```
xdman &
```

but this is the result:

```
lahcene@lahcene-Lenovo-B560:~$ xdman &
[1] 6422
lahcene@lahcene-Lenovo-B560:~$ Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at 

    java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
        at org.sdg.xdman.gui.XDMMainWindow.<init>(XDMMainWindow.java:116)
        at org.sdg.xdman.gui.XDMMainWindow.main(XDMMainWindow.java:2040)
```

nothing occur when I try to excite it from Classic Menu inducator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in Installing xdman in Ubuntu via terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481454/problem-in-installing-xdman-in-ubuntu-via-terminal)

Comment: @MartinThornton Hmm, not really. See my answer.

Comment: Please accept A.B.'s answer again as it answers your original question, then you may ask your new question as a new and separate question to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception is thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

Therefore install

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

and you could use a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdman
```

In my tests, there seems to be a refresh problem with the OpenJKD/OracleJava 7/8, after the start of the application. With Oracle Java 9, there isn't a problem

---

[image]

Resize the window and you should see this

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that i steel have the same problem, I've added the new PPA, and done the update ;but for the last command ,I've got the following:

Comment: Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xdman is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 468 not upgraded.

Comment: sorry for being so beginner, what do you mean by dist-apgrade, I don't like to upgrade to 15.04

Comment: because I have terrible internat connection, I steel dowloading the archives of upgrade (steel about 9 hours (more than 400MB))

Comment: sorry !! ,it doesn't work, after this command [xdman &] I've got: the same result (see the above question!!!)

Comment: I've run this command before this one -->sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdman

Comment: java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Installed: 1:4.7~trusty~NoobsLab.com
  Candidate: 1:4.7~trusty~NoobsLab.com
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.7~trusty~NoobsLab.com 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: openjdk-7-jre:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1
  Version table:
     7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1 0
        500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
this is the 1st output

Comment: THE SECOND OUTPUT IS:openjdk-7-jdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1
  Version table:
     7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1 0
        500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
N: Unable to locate package apt-cache
N: Unable to locate package policy

Comment: As I said, this problem was solved by the linked question.  Not you, until you edited it just now.

Comment: It solves the problem, but I steel have the old version (2014) not 2015

Comment: the problem have returned back after 'xdman &' i got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(ComparableTimSort.java:714)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:451)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:376)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:182)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:15

Comment: at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
 at org.sdg.xdman.gui.DownloadList.sort(DownloadList.java:202)
 at org.sdg.xdman.gui.DownloadList.loadDownloadList(DownloadList.java:198)
 at org.sdg.xdman.gui.DownloadList.<init>(DownloadList.java:45)
 at org.sdg.xdman.gui.XDMMainWindow.<init>(XDMMainWindow.java:118)
 at org.sdg.xdman.gui.XDMMainWindow.main(XDMMainWindow.java:2040)

Comment: @OmarOomar you've never accepted my answer and you've no upvote for me but I should give you an answer for a completely different question in the comments?

Comment: @OmarOomar even better, you have unaccepted my answer as you have a completely different problem. I would say, forget it.

Comment: @OmarOomar: The option `dist-upgrade` will do exactly what the `upgrade` command does and more, and is really the best to use so that packages are not held back. However, `dist-upgrade` does not and cannot upgrade you to a new Ubuntu version such as `15.04`.

Comment: I still think I did the right thing... but I'm sorry @A.B.

Comment: it works after repeating the above instructions many times @A.B